# How to know if app uses C2DM?

Tags: android, push, android-c2dm

Do you have concrete step to know if an app is using C2DM?
According to c2dm website;

"What Does the User See?
When mobile device users install an applications that include C2DM, they will get a permission from Android Market informing them that the application includes C2DM. They must approve the use of this feature to install the application."

This is the permission in the Manifest file of the C2DM app;

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.jumpnote.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.jumpnote.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Specifically i want to confirm if Skype, Talk, eBuddy uses C2DM, do you know the answer?

Does C2DM has equivalent display in;
In Settings > Applications > Manage applications > All> Talk > Permission ?

Comment: Sorry but...Is this a question or a statement? I've got the feeling you want to ask sth but the only question I can see you answer within your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question. You can tell if an app contains C2DM by checking the permissions it requests.

Comment: Yes, this is easy if it is opensource app. Just by looking its manifest we can know immediately. But how can we know if the app is like eBuddy, Skype or Gtalk?

Comment: You do not need an app to be open source to check the permissions it uses. They will be displayed to you when you install it and are listed in the settings afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Kuffs, you mentioned "They will be displayed to you when you install it". I tried to install eBuddy which according to its description that it uses C2DM. In the displayed "Allow access" screen there is no C2DM stated. Also in the Settings, C2DM as permission of eBuddy does not appear. Do you know other ways?

Comment: I just looked here https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ebuddy.android and the permission is clearly listed on the permissions page (press show all). Please mark your question as answered. thanks.